# YA novel about a girl who is transported to another world and plays chess

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a novel that I read in the early 2000s, about a normal girl who is transported into a magic kingdom.

Chess is a big part of this world, and it's somehow tied to magic. The girl has to go through trials and adventures in a court, and defeats the villain in the end with a chessboard. I believe at the end of the story, she's also able to travel back and forth between the real world and the magic one.

I think it was a standalone book at that point, but I am unsure if there are any sequels since then.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover of the book or any character or place names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might this be [*The Princess Pawn*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?154211) (2003) by Maggie L. Wood?  (Note that both [Amazon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/357657.The_Princess_Pawn) and [Goodreads](https://www.amazon.ca/Princess-Pawn-Maggie-L-Wood/dp/1894549295) give this a 2003/09/25 release date instead of ISFDb's March 2004.)

Quoting from the book's summary [on Goodreads](https://www.amazon.ca/Princess-Pawn-Maggie-L-Wood/dp/1894549295):

> Willow Kingswell thinks of herself as an ordinary fourteen-year-old. Although she has been hearing her grandmother's stories about the enchanted realm of Mistolear for as long as she can remember, being a princess is the furthest thing from her mind. What's worrying Willow these days is finding a way to get accepted by the in-crowd at her high school without betraying her friend Abby. Suddenly, **Willow finds herself magically transported to the real Mistolear**, where it turns out she actually does have a large family--and a royal one at that. Willow's courage and intellect are put to the test as she attempts to save the kingdom from **a terrifying spell that turns people into chess pieces**. Willow must decide the right course of action before the spell that threatens her newfound family takes away all her choices.

[image: Cover of "The Princess Pawn"]

Comment: Yes, that's the book I'm looking for!